# Is there any other option to solve the issue of phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am receiving this error when I try to use phpMyAdmin:

[image: This is the main issue here displayed]

```
MySQL said:
Cannot connect: invalid settings.
```

This is what I have in my configuration file:

[image: I have Tried Following method to solve this problem but I failed]

What am I missing?

Comment: The image show your attempt is just the config file, are those configs correct?

Comment: Yes all configuration are correct.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this on a recent Linux installation, then you cannot use `root` as the username you sign in with. You will need to use something different. The easiest way to solve the problem is to create a new user account and grant it complete access to the system.

So, if you're using Ubuntu Server, this is how you would do it:

From the Terminal (or via SSH):

1. Connect to MySQL as `root`:

   ```
   sudo mysql
   ```
2. Create the new user account:

   ```
   CREATE USER 'pmadmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'superSecretPassword!123';
   ```
3. Grant it permission to do anything:

   ```
   GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'pmadmin'@'localhost';
   ```
4. Update your phpMyAdmin settings to use `pmadmin` and `superSecretPassword!123` instead of your current settings

Be sure to change `pmadmin` and `superSecretPassword!123` to something better.

Comment: I am using it in windows...any solution for windows???